# Unable to get AuthenticationState to work in the latest Blazor Web template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In the latest .NET 8 Preview 7 they added a new [Blazor template](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8-preview-7/) with new RenderModes. Now you can have RenderModeServer and RenderModeWebassembly in the same project. I've been trying to add Authentication in the template that was introduced in the Visual Studio Preview update, but I can't get it to work. I followed the steps [from the old Webassembly documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) but I keep running into errors I had that seem to be related to Prerendering. In old projects I could fix this by adding something like below to my Host.cshtml file

```
@if (HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/authentication"))
{
    <component type="typeof(Client.App)" render-mode="WebAssembly" />
}
else
{
    <component type="typeof(Client.App)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
}
```

In this project however this doesn't seem to be the case though. And because of that I get the following errors:

```
InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(long asyncHandle, string identifier, string argsJson, JSCallResultType resultType, long targetInstanceId)
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<TValue>(long targetInstanceId, string identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, object[] args)
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<TValue>(long targetInstanceId, string identifier, object[] args)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, string identifier, object[] args)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService<TRemoteAuthenticationState, TAccount, TProviderOptions>.EnsureAuthService()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService<TRemoteAuthenticationState, TAccount, TProviderOptions>.GetAuthenticatedUser()
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService<TRemoteAuthenticationState, TAccount, TProviderOptions>.GetUser(bool useCache)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService<TRemoteAuthenticationState, TAccount, TProviderOptions>.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync()
```

This seems to occur when initializing the `AuthenticationStateProvider` as suggested in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#authentication-component)

Comment: In .net 8,you could set the render mode follow this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#webassembly-render-mode

Comment: you could call @attribute [RenderModeWebAssembly(false)] in your authentication page

Comment: Sadly even with RenderModeWebAssembly(false) I still get the same error

Comment: Have you tried to disable prerendering for the entire app follow the document? If it would work,try to create a component inherit RemoteAuthenticatorView Component and   disable prerenderding in the component